# Where can I find My Unity to download

Tags: unity

I'm really new here and I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my PC.  I have read about "My Unity" that was supposed to be part of 12.04 but wasn't included?  Does anybody know where I can find it?

Answer (score 6):

It *is* part of the available software in the Ubuntu repositories it is *not* installed by default, Install it from the Software Center.

[image: Install via the software center]

or use the Terminal: `sudo apt-get install myunity`.

Comment: I am now installing My Unity via Terminal, and it gave me the answer that "Unable to locate package myunity". What do I have to do ?

Comment: The package is no longer in the Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: You could try an alternative like Ubuntu Tweak or Unsettings.